# Call 3rd part apps from my widget

Tags: android

I've created an widget that will display if you've not outstanding on a long list of 3rd party applications.
I'm wanting the user to then be able to click on the icon and take them into that app just as if the widget was working like the main app launcher.

I've seen examples for things like the call logs and Messaging etc, but how should I be doing this for 3rd party apps (e.g. facebook, whatsapp etc) from within my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just send the intent to the 3rd party apps as if they are your own. To identify the 3rd party apps you can use the PackageManager: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html

Comment: Here's an example for facebook that works `Intent facebookIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.facebook.katana");
            facebookIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(facebookIntent);`